# How to load fonts from zip into Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I currently have the problem that I have a massive database of fonts, saved inside of a zip-archive and I don't want to extract it every time I grab a font (keeping performance in mind).

Is there a way in which I can grab a font and load it from the zip, straight into matplotlib?

I was able to do it just fine with Fonttools, but matplotlib seems to be quite hard to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could mount your zip file like a filesystem, see https://github.com/google/mount-zip

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import zipfile

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager

# Load the font from the ZIP file
with zipfile.ZipFile('your-font-pack-here', 'r') as zip_file:
    font_data = zip_file.extract('font-path.ttf')

# Add the font to the FontManager
font_manager.fontManager.addfont(font_data)

# Use the font in your plot
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'font-name'
plt.title('Hello World!', fontsize=24)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Do you know if there would be any problems, generating plots with different fonts over and over again? I plan to do some automization and create potentially thousands of them. I'm not that savvy when it comes to performance and memory utilization.

Comment: I'm not sure about using it at that scale. I would test for about a fourth of the estimated work load and see how it does. If it's performing slower than you need it to you may want to look into using a file manipulation tool that utilizes rust.

Comment: I just realized that it extracts every font, which I specifically don't want it to do :/

Comment: Hmmm, it shouldn't. The extract method from the zipfile module should only extract the fonts specified.